# JavaScript / JQuery array/object problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.fn.fieldValues = function(successful)
{
    var values = {};
    this.each(function()
    {
        if(strstr(this.name, '[]', true))
        {
            var tmp = this.name.replace(/\[\]/, '');
            if(typeof values[tmp] == 'undefined') values[tmp] = {};
            var x = 0;
            while(typeof values[tmp][x] != 'undefined') x++;
            values[tmp][x] = $(this).val();
        }
        else values[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
    return values;
}
```

problem is I get this array on php side:

```
array(['tagCloud'] => '[object Object]', ['status'] => 'Active'.....)
```

Why is tagCloud an object, how can I post a whole associative array to php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need **SerializeArray** instead, which works like **Serialize** but will make an array of name/value objects.

You should then turn this into a JSON string and pass through to your php process.  The php can then deserialize it back into an array of name/value objects and you can use the data however you want.

```
//build json object
var dataArray = $.makeArray($("form").serializeArray());
```

then pass through as a post:

```
// make ajax call to perform rounding
$.ajax({
    url: "/Rounding.aspx/Round/12",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: $.toJSON(dataArray),  <-- call to jQuery plug in
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: doSubmitSuccess
});
```

Here is a [link](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) to the JSON library I use to serialize the data

Answer (score 1):

Would encoding it as a json object and then decoding it in php (json_decode) work out?

Comment: Yes, I think it would, but JQuery native hasn't got json native, and every plugin I used sucks, anyone know of a good plugin for this to work?

Comment: You mean that PHP doesn't have JSON native?

Comment: No, but I found a solution, problem was that when using toJson in JQuery I got object of stdClass, I need to convert this to array on php side and it will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like you're re-inventing [`jQuery.fn.serialize`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize). jQuery handles inputs with `"[]"` in the name already:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="foo[]" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="foo[]" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="foo[]" value="3" />
</form>

<script>
alert(unescape($('form').serialize())) // "foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3"
</script>
```

php will parse that into an array OOTB.

Comment: Yes but serialize returns string, and I need array cause I will handle it diferent with my custom ajax function

Comment: @dfilkovi: define "handle it diferent" please.

Comment: Well first I fetch all data from a form, then I put other needed variables into that array, like wich php function to call (update, delete) and then pass that whole array to ajax. By using serialize, I would need to add all other variables to that string, but what when I'm not using serialize() but simple val() and want to pass only one variable. I would need to check If any of the passed variables are serialized strings and then update string with other variables, seems to me like an overkill.